# Git Installation Getting Stuck At the End On Windows 10

Tags: installation, git

As you can see from the installation screenshot I'm trying to install Git on another drive (I don't want to install on C:) and its getting stuck.

[image]

I'm installing it from the elevated command prompt as it's getting stuck at the end when trying to install the normal way.

I tried installing by selecting right clicking and selecting run as administrator , but still the same problem.

Installation is getting stuck on powershell using chocoletty as well.

[image]

Comment: 1) Is the A:\ drive "special" in some way?  2) Are you installing http://git-scm.com/download/win  or https://git-for-windows.github.io/ or https://desktop.github.com/ ?   3) Do you already have the item from question 2 installed already on C:\ drive and it works?  (I believe not, but wanted to confirm.)

Comment: I'm so sorry for the late response. Yes. I decided to install it on the C: and not bother about the A:. No A: is not special. It's just another partition on the HDD.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am experiencing the same problem on a windows 32bit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer may be too late for Alok Y but hope it helps anyone else facing the same problem!

I downloaded **git version 2.25.0**.windows.1 on my windows 10 64bit and tried to install it in A:(normal partition) drive instead of the C: drive through the executable installer.
It installed normally but in the end got stuck i.e the green bar was full but the installation successfull or other message did not show.

Here is what I did:

1.Open task-Manager

2.Select the installation

3.End_task

That's it.After that the installation successful message was printed for a second and the installation box closed by itself.

Checked if git-bash was working properly. As of now everything seems to work well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug in git installation.
In most of the cases when it reaches to the full installation green bar.. you can simply kill the git installation process from the task bar (by pressing ctrl+alt+del --> task manager).

After that add the git location to the PATH - The location that I used is as below -

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Restart your existing command prompt or application where you want to run git to reflect the git from PATH.